# How to get a URL QueryString Parameter in TMS Web Core?

Tags: delphi, query-string, url-parameters, url-parsing, tms-web-core

How can I get a QueryString Parameter Variable from the URL using Delphi code?

Let's assume I have a URL as follows:
https://www.example.com/index.html?first_name=shaun&last_name=roselt

How do I get `first_name` and `last_name` from the URL?

I want to do this via **Delphi only code** and not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a function called `GetQueryParam` within the `WebLib.WebTools` unit that comes with TMS Web Core.

You can use it as follows to get the `first_name` and `last_name` parameters:

```
uses WebLib.WebTools;

...

var
  FirstName, LastName: String;
begin
  FirstName := GetQueryParam('first_name');
  LastName := GetQueryParam('last_name');

  if (FirstName = '') then
    console.log('First Name Not Found!')
  else
    console.log('First Name is ' + FirstName);

  if (LastName = '') then
    console.log('Last Name Not Found!')
  else
    console.log('Last Name is ' + LastName);
end;
```

Comment: How does it behave on [edgy (but legal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Web_forms) cases like `https://site.web/?one=1&one=2&one=3`?

Comment: @AmigoJack It will return the last param which is "3" in your case.

Comment: upvote for question and answer, just what I was looking for, thanks Shaun