# How to set a URL QueryString Parameter in TMS Web Core?

Tags: delphi, query-string, url-parameters, tms-web-core

I'm able to get a param using the `GetQueryParam` function from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77183852/2908017) in the `WebLib.WebTools` unit to get parameters from the current URL.

One would assume the opposite of getting a param would be to set one using `SetQueryParam`, but no! `SetQueryParam` doesn't exist.

If I run the following code:

```
SetQueryParam('first_name', 'Shaun');
SetQueryParam('last_name', 'Roselt');
```

Then I get an error that says

> identifier not found "SetQueryParam"

What is the function and unit to set a Query Parameter using Delphi code?

---

For some added info. Here is the current function I wrote that I'm using to update the URL params:

```
procedure SetQueryParam(key, value, url: String);
begin
  asm
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    let re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|#|$)(.*)", "gi"),hash;

    if (re.test(url))
        if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null)
            url = url.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2$3');
        else {
            hash = url.split('#');
            url = hash[0].replace(re, '$1$3').replace(/(&|\?)$/, '');
            if (typeof hash[1] !== 'undefined' && hash[1] !== null) url += '#' + hash[1];
        }
    else
        if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null) {
            const separator = url.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '&' : '?';
            hash = url.split('#');
            url = hash[0] + separator + key + '=' + value;
            if (typeof hash[1] !== 'undefined' && hash[1] !== null) url += '#' + hash[1];
        }
    window.history.pushState({ path: url }, '', url);
  end;
end;
```

And then I can call the Delphi function as follows:

```
  SetQueryParam('first_name', 'Shaun');
  SetQueryParam('last_name', 'Roselt');
```

The above code works and it does what I need, but it's a mix between JavaScript and Delphi code. It's just messy and I don't like it.

Surely, there must be a built-in Delphi method for setting the URL param in TMS Web Core?

Comment: Where do you want to set the parameter? GetQueryParam works on the url the page was opened with. What url do you want to set parameters in? In one you are then going to use later on?

Comment: @NineBerry I want to set it within the current URL

Comment: @NineBerry I updated my question to show the code that I'm currently using for setting a URL param. I currently do it within the Delphi `asm` code block using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TMS Web Core has three global variables that you can use to access the commonly used functionality of the `document`, `window` and `console` objects in JavaScript.

This is how they are declared as global variables in the `Web` unit:

```
var
  document: TJSDocument;
  window: TJSWindow;
  console: TJSConsole;
```

From the global `window` variable, you can call `pushState` the same way as you use it in your JavaScript code.

[image]

By accessing the `window` object and using its function, you can rewrite your JavaScript code into native Delphi code.

Simple sample:

```
procedure TForm8.WebButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  NewUri: string;
begin
  NewUri:= window.location.href + '?a=b'; // Needs more logic
  window.history.pushState(nil, document.title, NewUri);
end;
```

As far as I am aware there is no built-in function in TMS Web Core to work with uris.